# Electrostatic Potential Energy

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, vectors

How is the boxed step , physically as well as mathematically justified and correct ?

Source:Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential_energy

As work done = $- \Delta U $. for Conservative force and it shouldn't matter whether we take $ds$ or $-dr$ ?

And when $dr$ is just a notation to specify the variable and the real thing behind it , is a limit , why is it that $dr$ is so important here .

[image]
Image : http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/download/file.php?id=43358&mode=view

Comment: Kindly edit my post a bit to prevent linkrot,thank you as I am not able to figure out how to upload images on stack exchange

Comment: Alright , thank you for editing

Comment: and how much reputation you require for uploading images ?

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62317/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you $dr$ is negative , so $|dr|=-dr.$ like $|-2|=-(-2)$ , evaluate using this , the sign ambiguity will dissolve .

Also displacements are measured w.r.t. some origin and here , origin can't be placed at $\infty$. So you base your origin at the point where the charge '$Q$' is located .